# Unparseable Date in android

Tags: java, android

```
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String eDate ="04/26/2013";
Date eDDte;
try {
    eDDte = df2.parse(eDate);
    System.out.println("Date: " + eDDte);
} catch(ParseException e){
}
```

Note: I got `unparseable date error` on 5th line. I already tried many other formats, but I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? do you want `format`?

Comment: The format `dd-MMM-yyyy` (separated with a dash `-`) is different from the actual date - `04/26/2013` (separated with a forward slash `/`).

Comment: @udaykiran i want date.

Comment: @Lion i already tried that. but same error.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad : `MMM` stands for a character month (three characters in the beginning), so the date is expected like `26-Apr-2013`. [See](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html).

Comment: @Lion i already tried MM also.

Comment: What input are you giving exactly? Paste here.

Comment: So, what mistake were you making?

Comment: @SagarMaiyad I Posted the answer check it once.

Comment: @udaykiran  i got this output. 13 Fri Apr 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013

Comment: @SagarMaiyad what output you expected ?. Give me the format of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the format to: "MM/dd/yyyy" to corectly parse your date: "04/26/2013"

This simple test prints: `Date: 26-Apr-2013`

```
public class DateFormatTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String eDate ="04/26/2013";
        Date eDDte;
        try {
            eDDte = df2.parse(eDate);
            System.out.println("Date: " + df3.format(eDDte));
        } catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SagarMaiyad It works, see the example above.

Comment: yeah, but its not perfect output which i want.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad OK, now I understood what you need. Updated the answer.

Comment: i need in date datatype.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad Refactor your printing/displaying code to get a `String` not a `Date`. Anyway, if it's a `Date`, it will be converted to a `String` by the `Date.toString()` in order to be displayed.

Comment: @dcernahoschi that is also correct. +1 for you sir.

Comment: Whenever you want to convert date from one timezone to another, you will need 2 SimpleDateFormat objects.



One will have the pattern of source dateformat.
The second will have the pattern of expected dateformat.

Comment: it's work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The date format dd-MMM-YYYY is not going to parse a date of 04/26/2013.  What *will* parse to it is a date format such as 26-APR-2013.

[Here's a list of the common date patterns.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)  In general, what your date pattern is doing is this:

- Take in a date, with leading zero, with a dash behind it
- Take in the three letter short-hand month (APR), with a dash behind it
- Take in the year

In order for SimpleDateFormat to parse it, it has to be *exactly* in that pattern.  Hence the exception.

If you don't want that pattern, then explore the more traditional date pattern of MM/dd/YYYY, which will match your date string.

Comment: Good catch sir. Exactly that is the problem. +1 for you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String eDate ="04/26/2013";
Date eDDte;
try {
    eDDte = df2.parse(eDate);
    System.out.println("Date: " + eDDte);
} catch(ParseException e){ }
```

Comment: I already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

First parse the date '04/26/2013' to 'MM/dd/yyyy' then parse it.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat ef2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String eDate = "04/26/2013";
    Date eDDte;
    try {
        Date nDate = ef2.parse(eDate);
        eDDte = df2.parse(df2.format(nDate));
        System.out.println("Date: " + eDDte);
        System.out.println("\nFormated Date:"+ df2.format(nDate));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Output:

```
Date: Fri Apr 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013

Formated Date:26-04-2013
```

Comment: i want date in second format.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad second format means ?

Comment: i want output like 26-04-2013 in date datatype.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad I updated this answer, check once.  ?